# Setup zustand and nextjs get hydration error

Tags: next.js, zustand

So this is my first time using Zustand and trying to set it up on my Nextjs project
but get this error

[image]

[image]

my Zustand setup is using slice pattern

```js
// store.ts
import { create } from "zustand";
import { createFishSlice } from "./slices/fishSlice";
import { createBearSlice } from "./slices/bearSlice";
import { CombinedSlicesType } from "@/app/_types/zustand";

export const useBoundStore = create<CombinedSlicesType>()((...a) => ({
  ...createBearSlice(...a),
  ...createFishSlice(...a),
}));
```

```js
// fishSlice.ts
import { CombinedSlicesType, FishSlice } from "@/types/zustand";
import { StateCreator } from "zustand";

export const createFishSlice: StateCreator<
  CombinedSlicesType,
  [],
  [],
  FishSlice
> = (set) => ({
  fishes: 220,
  addFish: () => set((state) => ({ fishes: state.fishes + 1 })),
});
```

```js
// bearSlice.ts
import { CombinedSlicesType, BearSlice } from "@/types/zustand";
import { StateCreator } from "zustand";

export const createBearSlice: StateCreator<
  CombinedSlicesType,
  [],
  [],
  BearSlice
> = (set) => ({
  bears: 110,
  addBear: () => set((state) => ({ bears: state.bears + 1 })),
  eatFish: () => set((state) => ({ fishes: state.fishes - 1 })),
});
```

this is custom hooks as mention here : https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/integrations/persisting-store-data#usage-in-next.js

```js
// useStore.ts 
"use client";

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useStore = <T, F>(
  store: (callback: (state: T) => unknown) => unknown,
  callback: (state: T) => F
) => {
  const result = store(callback) as F;
  const [data, setData] = useState<F>();

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(result);
  }, [result]);

  return data;
};

export default useStore;
```

and this is the component that consume the store

```js
"use client";

import useStore from "@/hooks/useStore";
import { useBoundStore } from "@/libs/zustand";
import React from "react";

function Bear() {
  const store = useStore(useBoundStore, (state) => state);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Bear : {store?.bears}</h1>

      <br />
      <button onClick={() => store?.addBear?.()}>+ add bear</button>
      <br />
      <br />

      <h4> {Math.random()}</h4>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Bear;
```

## Second Issue :Re-render

so i have a page @app/home/page.tsx
the bear is the same like the one above

```js
"use client";

import { Flex } from "antd";
import Bear from "@/components/pages/root/Bear";
import Fish from "@/components/pages/root/Fish";

export default function Home(props: any) {
  return (
    <>
      <Flex gap={200}>
        <Bear />
        <Fish />
      </Flex>
    </>
  );
}
```

```js
//Fish.tsx
import useStore from "@/hooks/useStore";
import { useBoundStore } from "@/libs/zustand";
import React from "react";

function Fish() {
  const store = useStore(useBoundStore, (state) => state);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Fish : {store?.fishes}</h1>

      <br />
      <button onClick={() => store?.addFish?.()}>+ add Fish</button>
      <br />
      <br />

      <h4> {Math.random()}</h4>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Fish;
```

[image]

if I add fish the bear component will re-render, so please advise how to set this up correctly and how to handle the hydration issue

also in this explanation zustand mentions to use devtools as the last
but they give example putting devtools first then persist, am I missing something?

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: I believe this should work. Use incognito mode and try again and see if you still get hydration errors. if you don't you probably need to clear cache or something